# Postinstall in cypress fork

Tags: node.js, github, gitlab, cypress

I created a fork of cypress in gitlab that has all the code. Now I am trying to run npm install using ssh for that repository and I'm getting this error:

```
> cypress@6.3.0 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\Portal-Development\development\devel\node\node_modules\cypress
> ./scripts/run-if-not-ci.sh yarn build

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN cypress-select-tests@1.5.9 requires a peer of cypress@3 || 5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\babel-plugin-add-module-exports\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchify\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@6.3.0 postinstall: `./scripts/run-if-not-ci.sh yarn build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@6.3.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-29T20_13_09_780Z-debug.log
```

Basically I want to be able to run cypress from my gitlab fork, make changes to it and test it as I go along.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The error was because the path was being back slashed rather than forward slashed. I changed it in the package.json and I got it working.